# Detailed properties of `FindInstance`

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, inequalities

Does anybody know where to read about how `FindInstance` works?

Specifically I want to use it in such a way that when it returns `{}` I want to be sure that no solution indeed exists.

Even more specifically, I have a bunch of conditions of the form `0 < x[1] < x[2] < x[3] <`..., `x[i] + x[j] == x[k] + x[l]` and `x[p] + x[q] != x[r] + x[s]`.

Most likely in this case this is indeed so, i. e. if `FindInstance` returns empty set this indeed means that no solutions exist, but I want to know for sure.

Comment: [The tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html) says "If `FindInstance[expr, vars, dom]` returns `{}` then this means that the Wolfram Language has effectively proved that `expr` cannot be satisfied for any values of variables in the specified domain".

Comment: The above quote is from "Equations and Inequalities over Domains" section.